# Jquery find by two attr values

Tags: jquery

I have table cells with attributes `data-position-x` and `data-position-y` with integer values. I want to find one certain cell by `x` and `y` values. Is it possible in jQuery? At the moment I can't figure out how I can pass two predicates to construction `$('[data-position-x="0"]');`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [multiple attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/) is what you are looking for:

```
$('[data-position-x="0"][data-position-y="0"]');
```

Answer (score 8):

Just simply pass 2 (or more) `[]` blocks to search for multiple attributes:

```
$('[data-position-x="0"][data-position-y="0"]');
```